# Gstreamer encode: Is there any way to add some additional information to Src element? so that i can use those information in Sink element's callback

Tags: gstreamer, encode

all
i'm new to gstreamer,i'm using gstreamer on the TDA4 platform to encode nv12 image as h264 video,  besides the image data, every nv12 image has some additional information which is need after h264 frame encoded. so as the title said, is there any way can help?

i have registered a sink callback to obtain the h264 frame encoded as the .png below,  but how can i get the additional information of the nv12 image?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFQpm.png)

i have noticed that src element has callbacks too, does this can help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByUwx.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should add the code under consideration to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 for more on this. You will increase the probability of others responding to your question if you invest the time to follow the stackoverflow guidelines.